# Extracting geographic coordinates/numerics from webpage

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I have some code to try to collect some information from a website:

I can connect and read in the HTML data using (thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71842278/extracting-links-from-a-drop-down-menu-using-rvest-rselenium/71843331#71842278)):

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4536L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
#navigate 
url = 'https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/a-bana/todas-las-zonas/l'
remDr$navigate(url)
#accept cookies
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()

#click on Zona
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="App"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div')$clickElement()

# read html page
html_full_page = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html()
```

I am a little stuck on trying to collect one piece of data. I run the following and want to extract the numeric results from:

```
html_full_page %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem') %>% 
  html_nodes('label') 

{xml_nodeset (4)}
[1] <label class="sui-AtomCheckbox sui-AtomCheckbox--medium is-checked"><span class="sui-AtomIcon sui-AtomIcon--small sui-AtomIcon--currentColor"><span><svg viewbox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19.2 5.4a1 1 0 0 1 1.669 1.095L ...
[2] <label class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-label" name="geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15007,0,0,0"><span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">A Baña</span><span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-ch ...
[3] <label class="sui-AtomCheckbox sui-AtomCheckbox--medium"><input type="checkbox" id="geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0" name="geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0" intermediate=""></label>
[4] <label class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-label" name="geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0"><span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Negreira</span><span class="re-GeographicSearchNext- ...
```

i.e. the `geosearch` part of the data.

I am trying to obtain the following from this part of the code:

1. -724,12,15,487,0,15007,0,0,0
2. -724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0

> ```
> >     [1] "<a class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator\" title=\"A Baña\"
> > href=\"/es/comprar/viviendas/a-bana/todas-las-zonas/l\"><div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeCheckboxField\"><div class=\"sui-MoleculeField
> > sui-MoleculeField--inline sui-MoleculeField--inline-reverse
> > sui-MoleculeField--fullWidth\">\n<div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeField-labelContainer\">\n<label
> > class=\"sui-AtomCheckbox sui-AtomCheckbox--medium\"><input
> > type=\"checkbox\" id=\"geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15007,0,0,0\"
> > name=\"geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15007,0,0,0\"
> > intermediate=\"\"></label><div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeField-nodeLabelContainer\"><label
> > class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-label\"
> > name=\"geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15007,0,0,0\"><span
> > class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal\">A
> > Baña</span><span class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-count
> > re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-count-is-child\">17</span></label></div>\n</div>\n<div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeField-inputContainer
> > sui-MoleculeField-inputContainer--aligned\"></div>\n</div></div></a>" 
> > 
> >     [2] "<a class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator\"
> > title=\"Negreira\"
> > href=\"/es/comprar/viviendas/negreira/todas-las-zonas/l\"><div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeCheckboxField\"><div class=\"sui-MoleculeField
> > sui-MoleculeField--inline sui-MoleculeField--inline-reverse
> > sui-MoleculeField--fullWidth\">\n<div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeField-labelContainer\">\n<label
> > class=\"sui-AtomCheckbox sui-AtomCheckbox--medium\"><input
> > type=\"checkbox\" id=\"geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0\"
> > name=\"geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0\"
> > intermediate=\"\"></label><div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeField-nodeLabelContainer\"><label
> > class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-label\"
> > name=\"geoSearch-724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0\"><span
> > class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal\">Negreira</span><span class=\"re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-count
> > re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-count-is-child\">52</span></label></div>\n</div>\n<div
> > class=\"sui-MoleculeField-inputContainer
> > sui-MoleculeField-inputContainer--aligned\"></div>\n</div></div></a>"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
html_full_page %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem') %>% 
  html_nodes('label') %>% 
  html_attr("name") %>%
  gsub("geoSearch-", "", .) %>%
  na.omit()

# [1] "724,12,15,487,0,15007,0,0,0" "724,12,15,487,0,15056,0,0,0"
# attr(,"na.action")
# [1] 1 3
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"
```